# Password Protect Static Page AppEngine HowTo?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, .htaccess, openid, .htpasswd

So I'm working with AppEngine (Python) and what I want to do is to provide OpenID Login setting a Default provider so the user can Log-In without problems using that provider. The thing is, I want to prompt the user a Password right after they login in order to show static content (HTML Pages); If the user doesn't enter the correct password then I want to redirect them to another page. The protection has to be server side please :) Any Ideas??

P.S. I'm seeking for a solution similar to ".htaccess/htpasswd" but for app engine.

Comment: Using the "Permissions settings" in app.yaml is not an option either because I want to manually send the password to the registered/loggable users, or if I can choose passwords for everyone would be cool too; but anyway... The basic idea is to protect the pages with one pre-defined password and send it to users

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, GAE does not support such setup (static password after OpenID login).

The only way I see to make this work would be to serve static content via your handler:

1. Client makes a request for static content
2. Your handler is registered to handle this URL
3. Handler checks is user is authenticated. If not, requests a password.
4. When authenticated, handler reads static file and sends it back to user.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, you can mimic the .htaccess style password with Google App Engine:

```
def basicAuth(func):
  def callf(webappRequest, *args, **kwargs):
    # Parse the header to extract a user/password combo.
    # We're expecting something like "Basic XZxgZRTpbjpvcGVuIHYlc4FkZQ=="
    auth_header = webappRequest.request.headers.get('Authorization')

    if auth_header == None:
      webappRequest.response.set_status(401, message="Authorization Required")
      webappRequest.response.headers['WWW-Authenticate'] = 'Basic realm="Kalydo School"'
    else:
      # Isolate the encoded user/passwd and decode it
      auth_parts = auth_header.split(' ')
      user_pass_parts = base64.b64decode(auth_parts[1]).split(':')
      user_arg = user_pass_parts[0]
      pass_arg = user_pass_parts[1]

      if user_arg != "admin" or pass_arg != "foobar":
        webappRequest.response.set_status(401, message="Authorization Required")
        webappRequest.response.headers['WWW-Authenticate'] = 'Basic realm="Secure Area"'
        # Rendering a 401 Error page is a good way to go...
        self.response.out.write(template.render('templates/error/401.html', {}))
      else:
        return func(webappRequest, *args, **kwargs)

  return callf

class AuthTest(webapp.RequestHandler):
  @basicAuth
  def get(self):
     ....
```

[How-To: Dynamic WWW-Authentication (.htaccess style) on Google App Engine](http://www.eriksmartt.com/blog/archives/882)

Comment: hey that's a good solution. consider using auth_header is None instead of auth_header == None.